# jQuery - div fade on/fade out - with background and content - time

Tags: jquery, html, fade

Thank you for looking at this problem in advance.

As a jQuery beginner I am trying to do combine 2 scripts to create 1 smoother outcome.. and it's not going so well.

The problem occurs that the content divs fade in and fade out at varying times to the background. And after about 3 changes the cycle can start to overlap. I've tried all the timing combos I can think of, so I thought that maybe the only real solution would be to combine the scripts. The 2nd problem is that the content change has no fade. So if I make the content divs 100%x100% with different backgrounds, the smoothness effect is lost.

**The final goal:** To have a Content Divs that have different backgrounds and content change with smoothly every 7-8 seconds.

At the moment this is what I have:

*SCRIPT*

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      //Preload images first 
    $.fn.preload = function() {
        this.each(function(){
            $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        });
    }
    $.fn.preload = function() {
        this.each(function(){
            $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        });
    }
    var images = Array("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Appearance_of_sky_for_weather_forecast,_Dhaka,_Bangladesh.JPG", "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Sky_over_Washington_Monument.JPG", "http://pplus.in.ua/uploads/posts/2014-10/1414742119_pasmur_1.jpg");

    $([images[0],images[1],images[2]).preload();

    // Usage:

    var currimg = 0;

    $(document).ready(function(){

        function loadimg(){

           $('#background').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500,function(){

                //finished animating, minifade out and fade new back in           
                $('#background').animate({ opacity: 0.7 }, 500,function(){

                    currimg++;

                    if(currimg > images.length-1){

                        currimg=0;

                    }

                    var newimage = images[currimg];

                    //swap out bg src                
                    $('#background').css("background-image", "url("+newimage+")"); 

                    //animate fully back in
                    $('#background').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500,function(){

                        //set timer for next
                        setTimeout(loadimg,7500);
                    });
                });
            });
         }
         setTimeout(loadimg,9000);

    });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
    var divs = $('div[id^="content"]').hide(),
        i = 0;

    function cycle() {
        $("#displayArea").html(divs.eq(i).html());
        i = ++i % divs.length; // increment i, and reset to 0 when it equals divs.length
    }

    setInterval(cycle, 9000);

    });
    </script>
```

*CSS*

```
#background {
position : fixed ;
bottom : 0 ;
left : 0 ;
z-index : -100 ;
background-image : url("http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs17/f/2007/153/1/4/Sky_Stock_1_by_PartWish.jpg"); 
width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
background-position: 50% 20%; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

div.index-caption {
position : absolute ;
left : 50% ;
top : 372px ;
display : block ;
padding : 18px ;
border : none ;
line-height : 1.3em ;
z-index : 1 ;
color : #fff ;
background : rgb(11, 43, 63) ;
text-transform : uppercase ;
font-size : 26px ;
margin-left : -470px;
}
```

*HTML*

```
<div id="background">
</div>

    <div id="displayArea">
        <div class="index-caption">
        Content 1
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="contentA">
    <div class="index-caption">
    Content 2
    </div>
</div>
<div id="contentB">
    <div class="index-caption">
    Content 3
    </div>
</div>
<div id="contentC">
    <div class="index-caption">
    Content 4
    </div>
</div>
<div id="contentD">
    <div class="index-caption">
    Content 5
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can probably imagine it is very messy but hopefully you can see where I am trying to get to.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fully documented, but be specific to what the problem you encounter is : loop not starting? Poor performance? Etc.

Comment: @Bonatoc Thank you. The problem occurs that the content divs fade in and fade out at varying times to the background. And after about 3 changes the cycle can start to overlap. I've tried all the timing combos I can think of, so I thought that maybe the only real solution would be to combine the scripts. The 2nd problem is that the content change has no fade. So if I make the content divs 100%x100% with different backgrounds, the smoothness effect is lost.

Comment: You're speaking of "soundbites". I don't see any code related to the triggering of such files... Are the audio files overlapping?

Comment: @Bonatoc sorry - soundbites meaning the content divs/captions

Comment: Maybe set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to better demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may simply use pure CSS : The thing is to give classes or ids to your images, and put them one under another in a container. **[In this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bonatoc/4nncsr5k/18/)**, AngularJS is only used for rapid prototyping.

The second slideshow is pure html, so Javascript is not required.

```
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    0% { opacity:0; -webkit-transform:translate(0px,0px) scale(0.93); }
    5% { opacity:1;  }
    25% { opacity:1;  }
    30% { opacity:0; -webkit-transform:translate(0px,0px) scale(1.0); } 
}

/*  ...  */

#CSS3Slideshow .img1 {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation:fade_start_opaque_alt 20s linear infinite; 
    -moz-animation:fade_start_opaque 20s linear infinite; 
        -webkit-animation-delay:0s; -moz-animation-delay:0s;

}
```

Of course, you can get rid of the Ken Burns effect by removing "scale" form the keyframes declarations.

FYI : 20 seconds divided by 4 images -> 5 seconds each.

Comment: Hi @Bonatoc thanks for this. The ToyMaker Lab is working we except I am struggling with the final step.

Comment: I would recommend using the logic in my Fiddle : only CSS is required.

Comment: Hi @Bonatoc thanks for this. The ToyMaker Lab is working we except I am struggling with the final step. That is to put the captions is different places - http://jsfiddle.net/d7ojz61y/ (although it doesn't work in this example it does with my editor, i think I've put it in fiddle wrong :S ) - I was wondering if in the script section where is has "var titles =" I could put each one in a div.. e.g. <div class="caption1">Title Text</div> so that each load with different css placement settings

Comment: Ah ok. I will play with that now :) And let you know how i get on

Comment: Again, sorry for the JQuery plugin, you can achive this simply with CSS : Here's an new JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bonatoc/owm771sf/3/

Comment: Here's your fixed JSFiddle (Toymaker Lab) : http://jsfiddle.net/bonatoc/d7ojz61y/2/ - You don't need to have script tags in the JSFiddle Javascript section. Your Ken Burns works nicely, don't forget to stretch to 120%/120% your images, and put them into a container which will be at z-index:0, width:100% and height:100%. You need a frame with overflow:hidden, and have the images sizes bigger than the container (see my pure CSS JSFiddle).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66357/discussion-between-lozano-and-bonatoc).